# JSON date to Model C# DateTime

Tags: c#, json, api

I have a ASP.NET MVC API site, where one of my models require a DateTime, but no matter what i do, it won't accept the data i send it as a valid model!

I have tryed

```
{"Owner":"s083151","Permissions":"public","Name":"SomeRandomMeeting","Begin":"2013-03-28T13:00:00.2124557+01:00","End":"2013-03-28T17:00:00.2124557+01:00","Url":"MyRandomUrl"}
```

and

```
{"Owner":"s083151","Permissions":"public","Name":"SomeRandomMeeting","Begin":Date(1364234400),"End":Date(1364248800),"Url":"MyRandomUrl"}
```

and

```
{"Owner":"s083151","Permissions":"public","Name":"SomeRandomMeeting","Begin":1364234400,"End":1364248800,"Url":"MyRandomUrl"}
```

and

```
{"Owner":"s083151","Permissions":"public","Name":"SomeRandomMeeting","Begin":"1364234400","End":"1364248800","Url":"MyRandomUrl"}
```

But none of it, is accepted as Model.IsValid, what am i doing wrong?

I use fiddler to test the requests
here are my Request headers

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
```

The data model

```
[DataContract]
public class MeetingModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Owner { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Permissions { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Begin { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(75)]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string MeetingId { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }

    public List<UserModel> Hosts { get; set; }

    public List<UserModel> Participants { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: so... why `Begin` and `End` are `string` instead of `DateTime`?

Comment: @AgustinMeriles sorry missed some of my debugs, they where suppose to be DateTime, it has been fixed

Comment: Did you try putting `Date` between `"`s? `{"Owner":"s083151","Permissions":"public","Name":"SomeRandomMeeting","Begin":"Date(1364234400)","End":"Date(1364248800)","Url":"MyRandomUrl"}`

Comment: @AgustinMeriles yes tryed that same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the date field like this, between slashes, worked for me:

```
{"Owner":"s083151",
 "Permissions":"public",
 "Name":"SomeRandomMeeting",
 "Begin":"/Date(1364234400)/",
 "End":"/Date(1364248800)/",
 "Url":"MyRandomUrl"}
```

If you are generating the JSON with C# code, be careful to add the scape backslash:

```
"\/Date(1364234400)\/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it is not because of the date, but rather because of the typo: you have `Permissions` (plural) property in your class, but `Permission` (singular) in JSON.

As for date formats, Scott Hanselman had a [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx) about that, from which it looks like the format that the default JSON model binder will understand looks like "2013-03-21T00:00:00" (and seems to be a part of [ISO 8601 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)).

Comment: Thank you, but sadly was that only an error when i typed it in here, in my tests did i spell it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/DatesInJSON.htm, the JSON standard is "2012-03-19T07:22Z". Could you try that?

Edit: just tried a GET on some of my code, and I got "OrderTime":"2013-03-21T12:58:15.053".